# SQL time difference calculation between rows and multiple ins and outs

Tags: sql, datetime, time, google-bigquery

Let's say a document making process includes several stages (1,2,...,8). A ticket is made to track the progress of each document. Everytime any change is made in the ticked it is stored as a modification and its time is stored. But we only care about the time it's stage was changed. There maybe a case where a document is sent back to some previous stage so it went through a lot of back and forth between stages.

I want to calculate the mean, median and max time each document spent in each stage. Say the table looks something like this (Ignore the details):

| Document Name | modification time | stage name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Doc 1 | 01/01/2023 06:00:00 | Stage 1 |
| Doc 1 | 01/01/2023 07:00:00 | Stage 1 |
| Doc 1 | 02/01/2023 06:00:00 | Stage 2 |
| Doc 2 | 02/01/2023 07:00:00 | Stage 1 |
| Doc 2 | 04/01/2023 06:00:00 | Stage 2 |
| Doc 1 | 05/01/2023 06:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| Doc 1 | 05/01/2023 14:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| Doc 1 | 05/01/2023 15:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| Doc 2 | 05/01/2023 15:30:00 | Stage 3 |
| Doc 1 | 05/01/2023 16:00:00 | Stage 3 |
| Doc 1 | 05/01/2023 17:00:00 | Stage 2 |

In some cases, there is a modification time but the stage doesn't change cause something else in the ticket changed, which isn't of our concern.

Edit: The result can be in any form as long as I get the mean, median and max values of time for docs for each stage.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result - i.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you'er using. (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: @SelVazi, those MD style tables are such a waste of screen height. Now I have to scroll up/down to read all of it on my laptop. (Which means I leave this for someone else to answer.)

Comment: @jarlh The end result can be anything as long as I get the mean, median and max values. It is not the end table I desire but the conclusion. Also, I've added the dbms thanks!

Comment: @jarlh true but MD styles still recommended !

Comment: @Deboparna could you share the expected output from the simple data ? show us mean, median and max values per document

Comment: @SelVazi So to break it down: Doc1 spent 24hrs in stage 1 (from 01/01/2023 06:00:00 to 02/01/2023 06:00:00) and doc 2 spent 47 hrs in stage 1 (02/01/2023 07:00:00 to 04/01/2023 06:00:00). So avg time spent in stage one is (24+47)/2 = 35.5.